# how to send Windows to commands to a job which is running inside a pipleline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Hi i have a jenkins job called Handler which need these windows commands to get libraries and to execute sucessfully

nuget sources Add -Name library -Source url

nuget restore c:\jenkins\workspace\ELD-Workspace\Handler

Where ELD-Workspace is a Repo in jenkins 
Handler is a job inside this Repo

Im writing a jenkins pipline called Handler_pipline which run "Handler" job
im trying to move those above commands to a pipline so that pipline can be inject then in Handler job.
Please help me with your solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can write `bat "my command"` or `powershell "my command"` and it will execute the command on the windows agent. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script).

By the looks of it, you might also need to use [dir](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-dir-code-change-current-directory) to change the current working director to `Handler`.